# найти символ \ в строке

Tags: java, char

в общем нужно узнать номер первого вхождения символа "\" в строке. но `string.indexOf("\");` не работает.  и `string.indexOf('\034');` ничего не дает.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, если я правильно понял эта конструкция возвращает либо true либо false, следует ли из этого, что ее всю можно запихнуть в if else, если да, то как?

Answer (score 7):

Символ обратного слэша служебный и его нужно экранировать:

```
string.indexOf("\\");
```